# python 2.7 def error

Tags: python, function

```
def h(x):
     x = ((x[0])*len(x))
     return x
```

when i print it, it goes

```
h(he)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    h(he)
NameError: name 'he' is not defined
```

Comment: i can't get this website to indent but i indented in the program properly

Comment: ¿Is "he" declared?, can be spelling error?

Comment: Maybe you mean h('he') ?

Comment: what do you mean declared?  sorry, i'm beginner

Comment: omg thank you!!!! audionuma
it was the quotations :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe mean to pass `he` as a string? `'he'` would be the appropriate way then.

```
def h(x):
     x = ((x[0])*len(x))
     return x

print(h('he'))
```

`>>>  hh`

Comment: @hihidsdsd feel free to accept the answer if this solved your problem.